# Problem with www version of domain in zone file

Tags: bind

I am trying to create a zone file which points example.com and www.example.com to my server's IP address.  I read the docs, but am still having a hard time with it.  Currently, the non-www version works, but the www doesn't.  I don't get an config errors when I start bind.  Here is my zone file:

```
$TTL 86400

@ IN SOA ns1.myserver.com.  postmaster.myserver.com. (
                        2010121801      ; serial number YYMMDDNN
                        1800 ; Refresh
                        600 ; Retry
                        864000 ; Expire
                        1800 ; Min TTL
                        )
                IN NS ns1.myserver.com.
                IN NS ns2.myserver.com.


IN A 99.99.99.99
www IN CNAME @
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: the www version just doesn't resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make an entry like

www     IN        99.99.99.99

Comment: I think you mean 'www in A 99.99.99.99' but yes, this is how I generally handle this.

Comment: here's the final version that works


$TTL 1800

@ IN SOA ns1.myserver.com.  postmaster.myserver.com. (
                        2010121904      ; serial
                        1800 ; Refresh
                        600 ; Retry
                        864000 ; Expire
                        1800 ; Min TTL
                        )
                IN NS ns1.myserver.com.
                IN NS ns2.myserver.com.

IN A 99.99.99.99
@ IN A 99.99.99.99
www IN A 99.99.99.99